# Occasional Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < on production environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm running a react app locally, on a sandbox server, and on a production server. I only encounter the unexpected token error on the production server sometimes. The console points to a chunk.js file. When I refresh, the error disappears and the page renders correctly. The start scripts on th sandbox and production servers are the same:

```
npm run build
serve -s build -l 12228 -n
```

The npm version on the production server is 12.19.0, on sandbox it's 13.11.0 and 12.13.1 locally.

My script tag in my index.html:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-180136700-1"></script>
<script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-180136700-1');
 </script>
```

I use react-router.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: show us your script tag on index.html and do you use react-router ?

Comment: That looks like an HTML error message where something else (like JSON) is expected.

Comment: I've updated the post thanks. Yes I use react-router @RajaJaganathan

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I thought so too initially, but if that was the case, why would it only happen in the production environment?

Comment: Because the error is caused by something that's different in that environment (data, settings, libraries...). Ideally, it'd be great to find the error location (not sure if it's unknown).

Comment: The browser console just points me to a .chunk.js file. 1 line, almost 4000 columns so I can't pinpoint

Comment: @PapaYawOfori-Afriyie where is the app bundle script tag?

Comment: @RajaJaganathan I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @PapaYawOfori-Afriyie usually we might have something like this <script src="js/app.js"></script>, we need to add / in front of js in path like scr="/js/app.js"

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I import app.js as a react component in my index.js.

Comment: I can't provide an answer because I don't know anything about React. But the single-line chunk.js file must be a minified script and, as such, you could expect a matching chunk.js.map file so the browser console can find the code location in the original code. If you aren't getting one, perhaps you need to change a setting somewhere in your build script.